# MVC Pass value/parameter from controller to View

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, parameters

what i'm trying to achieve:
1. fill up form
2. save into database
3. redirect user to another view that displays some details (referenceID)

so here's what i have

controller:

```html
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public ActionResult Create(ClearanceViewModel myViewModel, TClearance clearance, TRefsNum referenceNo)
{
  var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
  var stringChars = new char[8];
  var random = new Random();
  for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
  {
      stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
  }
  var finalString = new String(stringChars);
  string refNo = DateTime.Now.Year + finalString;
  items.RefNum = refNo;


  db.TClearances.Add(items);
  db.SaveChanges();

  return RedirectToAction(items.RefNum, "displayRef");
}
```

code above does save to database whatever user has input then redirect to view "displayRef" and items.refNum is the value that i'm trying to pass to view

view:

```html
@model RDMSPNPOnlineClearance.Models.TClearance

@{
    var getRef = Model.RefNum;
}

this is your ref number: @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RefNum, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
```

code above, is trying to get the expected value "items.refNum" and use the value to display it to the user.

so what actually happening is, user fill ups, saves to db, then redirected to "displayRef" view. no problem in saving part. the problem is im not getting the refNum in the displayRef view. the url changes to something like:
Localhost:55433/items.refNum/view

so, how do i pass that value to be displayed to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need `RedirectToAction`? Can you not just return the view...

```
return View("displayRef", items.RefNum);
```

If you have to use `RedirectToAction`, this means you're redirecting to a controller action and you must specify it like so...

```
return RedirectToAction("Action","controller", new {@id=id});
```

Also your model in the view is incorrect, you're binding a `string` refNo, but at the top of your view stating that you want to bind a class `RDMSPNPOnlineClearance.Models.TClearance`

Comment: That's an optional parameter. For example you provide the id of a record you want to view, so that would be an input param in your action method

Comment: so i put it like, new {@id=items.refNum}? and what shud be the class i'm gonna bind? is there any other workaround to this?

Comment: @silver01 You just need to return a view by the looks of it though, and not bother with RedirectToAction. Also see my edit re: model

Comment: yes, i do need to return the view with the details saved in the database, so after creating, it will display the inputs to the user in reference with the refNum

Comment: Well in that case it looks like you need to return `items` as your model to pass into the view you're going to use as a summary. Just looking at your code though, it won't even compile as you haven't even defined `items` anywhere